# Simple for loop over nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, networkx

I have a network (twitter_handles) containing tree twitter handles as nodes, I'd like to loop over the nodes to print each node one at the time

```
for node in twitter_handles.nodes():
    print(twitter_handles.node())
```

which I would expect to give me:

```
'twitterHandle1'
'twitterHandle2'
'twitterHandle3'
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried with nodes_iter() but that prints out 3x `dict_keyiterator object at 0x10c432d18`. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to print `node` instead which is the loop item in each iteration.

Comment: you input is a networkx graph G right?

Comment: Thanks you! It works. I've been staring at this thing for too long...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/graph.html#networkx.Graph) shows an example of iteration through the nodes of a graph, at the sub-heading `Shortcuts`.

Corresponding to that, `twitter_handles.nodes()` is a `NodeView` object. You can iterate over that to get your nodes sequentially. If you're interested in accessing each node's dictionary, that can be done by

```
for node in twitter_handles.nodes():
    print(twitter_handles.nodes[node])
```

Comment: This solution does not work when the nodes are alphabetic or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate, as follows:

```
for node in list(G7.nodes(data=True)):
    print(node)
```